# Why does adding columns to group by increases rows returned

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why would adding columns to the select list and group by in query increase the number of rows returned?  For instance, below is my basic query, but if I add columns, I get more rows returned.  The more columns added, the more rows returned.  It seems the where clause conditions should be the only thing controlling the rows that are returned.

Example Query:

```
select pobj_name, max(prev) prev 
from pfmc_part 
where pmodel in ('PN-DWG', 'NO-DWG') and pstatus = 'RELEASED' 
group by pobj_name 
order by pobj_name
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you add a `WHERE` clause, it filters the set of rows which will be handed down next to the `GROUP BY`, so `WHERE` is applied *before* groups.  The rows which will be grouped and on which aggregates like `SUM(),MAX(),MIN(),COUNT()` will be performed have already been limited to those matching the `WHERE` conditions before `GROUP BY` is applied.

As to why you get more rows when adding columns into `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` -- well, that's how `GROUP BY` aggregates work.  If you add additional columns into `SELECT` you must also group them (in most RDBMS) and as long as the values differ across rows, they will result in more grouped rows.

Consider this table:

```
Name   Score
John   2
Bill   3
John   1
```

A single `GROUP BY` on `Name` will collapse the `John` rows into one:

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Score) AS total
FROM scores
GROUP BY name

Name   total
John   3
Bill   3
```

Now consider this table, which has another column for sport.  Here, `John` has 2 different sports represented while Bill has only 1.  To include both `Name, Sport` in the `SELECT` list they must both also be in the `GROUP BY`.  The similar values across rows collapse into groups, but now `John` has *two* sets of similar values to group:

```
Name  Sport    Score
John  Baseball  3
John  Bowling   9
Bill  Baseball  10
Bill  Baseball  6
John  Bowling   12

SELECT Name, Sport, SUM(Score) AS total
FROM scores
GROUP BY Name, Sport

Name  Sport    total
John  Baseball 3
John  Bowling  21
Bill  Baseball 16
```

So adding additional columns to the `GROUP BY` will result in more output rows if the columns have dissimilar values across rows.

Applying a `WHERE` clause to this second table to look for only `John` rows, would eliminate all `Bill` rows *before* applying groups. The result would be two rows.

```
SELECT Name, Sport, SUM(Score) AS total
FROM scores
-- Filter with a WHERE clause this time
WHERE Name = 'John'
GROUP BY Name, Sport

-- Results in only John's rows
Name  Sport    Score
John  Baseball 3
John  Bowling  21
```

Comment: I understand now. Excellent explaination, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the table StudentScores:

```
+-----------+------------+-------+
| Last_Name | First_Name | Score |
+-----------+------------+-------+
| Smith     | Bob        |    90 |
| Smith     | Bob        |    85 |
| Smith     | Alice      |   100 |
| Smith     | Alice      |    90 |
| Johnson   | Evelyn     |    80 |
| Johnson   | Evelyn     |    85 |
+-----------+------------+-------+
```

This query:

```
SELECT Last_Name, MAX(Score) Score
FROM StudentScores
GROUP BY Last_Name
```

Results:

```
+-----------+-------+
| Last_Name | Score |
+-----------+-------+
| Smith     |   100 |
| Johnson   |    85 |
+-----------+-------+
```

However, this query:

```
SELECT Last_Name, MAX(Score) Score
FROM StudentScores
GROUP BY Last_Name, First_Name
```

Results:

```
+-----------+-------+
| Last_Name | Score |
+-----------+-------+
| Smith     |    90 |
| Smith     |   100 |
| Johnson   |    85 |
+-----------+-------+
```

So what's different?  Well, `'Smith'` is a `Last_Name` of two students:

```
SELECT Last_Name, First_Name, MAX(Score) Score
FROM StudentScores
GROUP BY Last_Name, First_Name
```

Results:

```
+-----------+------------+-------+
| Last_Name | First_Name | Score |
+-----------+------------+-------+
| Smith     | Bob        |    90 |
| Smith     | Alice      |   100 |
| Johnson   | Evelyn     |    85 |
+-----------+------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a new group-by increases the number of results you see beacuase each `group by` partitions the data in another way.

If you are using only an aggregate function you only get a single row result, The more finely you group the data the more result rows you will see

The `where` clause controls the inputs to the grouping perfomed by the `group by`. A `having` clause if present would control the results returned to the user.

Comment: Yes, I see that now.  Thanks very much for the reply.